# How do I delete a a label/button based on its name? WPF Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to delete a label and a button based on their name but unfortunately the option to remove them (that I know of) is through Children.Remove where it only accepts the actual label/button itself and not their name. I needed the name since it's the one that determines which X button belongs to who.

```
Label labels;
Button buttons;
int counter;

private void button_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Content = counter.ToString();
        lbl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        lbl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        lbl.FontSize = 50;
        lbl.Name = "lbl" + counter;
        labels = lbl;

        Button bt = new Button();
        bt.Content = "X";
        bt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        bt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        bt.Name = "btn" + counter;
        buttons = bt;

        bt.Click += Button_Click;

        grid.Children.Add(lbl);
        grid.Children.Add(bt);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grid.Children.Remove(labels.Name = "btn" + counter);
        grid.Children.Remove(buttons);
    }
```

The grid.Children.Remove(labels.Name = "btn" + counter); is not correct but hopefully it tells how I kinda wanted it to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first get the child element using a LINQ `Where` expression:

```
var child = grid.Children.OfType<Control>().Where(x => x.Name == "btn" + counter).First();
```

And then call `Remove`:

```
grid.Children.Remove(child);
```

Comment: The Name on x.Name is getting underlined red and it says "system.windows.controls.uielementcollection' does not contain a definition for 'Name'".

Comment: It compiles at my end, maybe you copied it before my last edit?

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you the Control replaced the UIElements. It's working now. I am experiencing something though, when I add twice, I can remove the last one but the first one brings up "Additional information: Sequence contains no elements" when I try to click its X button.

Comment: Then you should call `FirstOrDefault()` and check `child` for `null`.

Comment: Is it because I only have one variable for the newly created label/button and if I create it twice, it would only recognize the most recent one since the previous ones were replaced? Should I create the labels/buttons through an array?

Comment: When I put the FirstOrDefault(), it deletes the most recent one but nothing happens when I click the previous X buttons.

Comment: The counter is correct. Have you tried clicking the button that creates the label and button twice? it would output 1 with an x and 2 with an x. I could delete the 2 using its x but when I try to remove the 1 with its own x, it doesn't work.

Comment: Decrement the counter when removing the child control?

Comment: Indded @MaxJ. That is my idea too.

Comment: Oh, awesome! Thank you so much guys!